# Specifying tocloft package lengths - XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, tocloft, times, setlength

I'm using XeLaTeX compiler to create my pdf documents.
Recently I had to adjust some lengths in **tocloft** table of contents, for example I tried changing `\cftbeforechapskip` using `\setlength` command -- but I keep getting two errors: **Undefined control sequence** and **Missing \begin{document}**.

Please note that I have to have Times font in my document (so I included the way I set it up in code example).

Using `\setlength` with other (not tocloft) lengths sometimes gives warnings but works nevertheless.

Here is my code example:

```
%------------------ basic document settings -------------------------------
\documentclass[14pt]{article} % шрифт и формат документа

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[]{Times New Roman}
%------------------ ToC setup -------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0cm} %this line gives errors

\author{Мамонтов Иван, Т12О-402Б-20}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Part one}
\subsection{Subpart one}

\section{Part two}

\end{document}
```

This code example produces log file with these errors:

> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. l.9 \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0cm}

> Undefined control sequence.  \cftbeforechapskip l.9 \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0cm}

> LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [14pt].

Comment: You're using `article` that has no chapters. Unrelated, there is no `14pt` option for article.

Comment: Actually, your first error message is `Undefined control sequence. \cftbeforechapskip`, which has been explained by @egreg. The other message, `Missing \begin{document}.`, is just a consequence of this error. So either use the document class `report` instead of `article`, or don't use `\cftbeforechapskip`, as there will be no chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tocloft` package only defines `\cftbeforechapskip`, together with all other `\cftchap[...]` commands or parameters, only if the document class provides for `\chapter`.

```
\if@cfthaschapter
  \newlength{\cftbeforechapskip}
    \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1.0em \@plus\p@}
  \newlength{\cftchapindent}
    \setlength{\cftchapindent}{0em}
[...]
\fi
```

Setting `\cftbeforechapskip` with a class that hasn't chapters would be useless, because it would never be employed.

In your case you probably wanted to set `\cftbeforesecskip`.

```
%------------------ basic document settings -------------------------------
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % шрифт и формат документа

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tocloft}

%%%% settings

% languages and fonts
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% toc
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\author{Мамонтов Иван, Т12О-402Б-20}

\tableofcontents

\section{Part one}
\subsection{Subpart one}

\section{Part two}

\end{document}
```

I fixed the `14pt` option (that doesn't exist) to `12pt`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot that I use sections instead of chapters